# is xmpp good for chat room applicaition (not messenger)?

Tags: protocols, xmpp, chat, social-networking

do you any experiences with xmpp protocol for chat room applications?
not for messenger IM.

Comment: If not for messenger, then what?

Comment: a chat room is different in that you login into a room and talk to strangers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XMPP supports chat rooms with the XEP-0045 extension. Most clients (even mobile clients) seem to support it. I know Jabber.org and many other XMPP servers support chat rooms. Some even support Jabber -> IRC Transports, so you can connect to IRC from XMPP.